# Trying to parse possibly very deeply nested xml file with Nokogiri

Tags: ruby-on-rails, xml, nokogiri

I have been trying to find specific enough example on how to proceed. I am creating xml file with Builder for export/import use. I am exporting this file from app and when importing I want to create new records to database based on this xml file. With relations between models intact.

I have category with several questions, each question has several answers which might trigger one or more further questions.

I made simplified version of my xml file: https://gist.github.com/1225431

As I am doing it by myself, I am also open to suggestions if I should prepare that xml file differently.

```
questions = doc.css('questions')
```

This is where I am now, so right at the beginning. All the examples I have found have been for totally different kind of problems (or so I feel).

Am I even using right tool for this job? Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nokogiri is a great XML/HTML parsing library for Ruby, so you're definitely using the right tool for the job. Since you're parsing an XML document, you ought to use [XPath](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XPath) instead of CSS selectors. Fortunately, [Nokogiri has you covered](http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML/Node.html#method-i-xpath).

The Nokogiri documentation has a few [basic, helpful usage tutorials](http://nokogiri.org/tutorials). [This one](http://nokogiri.org/tutorials/parsing_an_html_xml_document.html) answers your question.

Here is a code example specific to your question. Hopefully this is enough to get you started:

```
require 'nokogiri'

# Reads the `example.xml` file from the current directory.
file    = File.read("example.xml")

# Uses Nokogiri::XML to parse the file.
doc     = Nokogiri::XML(file)

# Iterate over each <question> element and print 
# the text inside the first <name> element of each.
doc.xpath("//question").each do |q|
    puts q.at("name").text

    # Iterate over each <selection> element within the
    # current question and print its <name> and <conditional> 
    # line "name: conditional"
    q.xpath("./selection").each do |selection|
        puts "#{selection.at("name").text}: #{selection.at("conditional").text}"
    end

    # Same as above, but use variables.
    q.xpath("./selection").each do |selection|
        name                = selection.at("name").text
        conditional = selection.at("conditional").text

        puts "#{name}: #{conditional}"
    end
end
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I tried both xpath and css, but always ended up stuck. I ended up kludging my way through this. I made own nodesets for each type, questions and selections. And then looped trough them to get them inside the database. Not pretty, but at least it works.

Comment: I read and read through the tutorials on nokogiri.org, but wasn't able to wrap my head around it.

Comment: One question though. Wouldn't this `doc.xpath("//question")` select also the questions that are inside selection as conditional questions? That was my major headache.

Comment: Yes, it will return all `<question>` blocks. If you're looking for only the top level, you'd want to do something like,`doc.xpath("//questions/question")` which would limit it to only `<question>` elements that were direct children of `<questions>`.

Comment: I modified my code to a bit. Speed improvement of roughly 30%. I think the issue that I struggled most at start and one that didn't pop up from any tutorial was this: `q.xpath("./selection")` That dot before slash there made all the difference.